# Jinja2: Flask's url_for() combined with Knockout's attr binding

Tags: python, knockout.js, flask, jinja2

I'm using Flask and Knockout together in a web application with Jinja2 as the templating engine. In my Flask application I have two routes: `/accounts/` and `/accounts/<int:acc_id>/`, which look something like this:

```
@app.route("/accounts/")
@login_required
def accounts():
    return render_template("accounts.html")


@app.route("/accounts/<int:acc_id>/")
@login_required
def account(acc_id):
    return render_template("account.html",
        account_id=acc_id)
```

The `/accounts/` route loads an HTML page with a Knockout view model. The view model then AJAX loads a list of accounts into an `observableArray` and renders something like this:

```
<!-- ko foreach: accounts -->
    <span data-bind="text: name></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The `/accounts/<int:acc_id>/` route displays information about a single account.

What I'm trying to do is create an `href` attribute on each account in the HTML snippet above using `url_for()`, passing the account's id as a parameter. I'm having trouble making the Python call to `url_for()` with a parameter from the Knockout model.

A couple of  variations I've tried so far:

**Concatenating the id into the url_for function call:**

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: '{{ url_for('account', acc_id=' + id() + ' }}'}">
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
</a>
```

This produces a `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '+ id() +'` since it reads the call to id() as a string literal.

**Creating a function in the view model that returns the url_for string:**

```
self.accountUrl = function(account_id) {
    return '{{ url_for("admin.account", acc_id=' + account_id + ') }}';
};
```

and calling it like so:

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: $root.accountUrl(id()) }">
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
</a>
```

This results in the href attribute being set as the string literal returned from `accountUrl()`, i.e. the HTML looks like this:

```
<a href='{{ url_for("account", acc_id=1) }}'>
```

I feel like there's something I must be overlooking here. Any ideas?

Comment: Is `url_for()` a server-side function?  Or does it run on the client in the browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your python code (`url_for`) runs on the server side when the HTML is generated but the Knockout code runs your in the browser when the page is rendered. So you cannot pass variables from Knockout into to the python `url_for` method.

What you can do is to generate only the `/accounts/` and build the rest of the URL with KO:

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: '{{ url_for('account') }}' + '/' + id() }">
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: Ah, of course, that makes sense now that you say it. I feel a bit silly now.

Your solution won't work, unfortunately, since Flask's url_for() simply fails if you don't supply the required parameters. However, I can work around it by other means. Thanks a lot!