# Passing JQuery array to Flask variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

There's a similar titled question on SO, but it really doesn't have anything to do with my issue.

So, I have some JQuery arrays that I create in a function. Now, I would like to set some flask variables to those JS arrays in that same function. The reason I would like to do this is so that I then set the `href` of an element and route my user.

Here's the current JS code:

**JQuery**

```
//Filter Search
$(function() {
    $('#filter_search').click(function() {               
        var entities = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($('#filterform').serializeObject())).checkboxes;  
        var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($('#filterform').serializeObject())).checkboxeslower;
        if(typeof data == "string") { 
            data = $.makeArray(data); 
        }

        //Here I want to set Flask variables like {{entities}} and {{data}}

        //Then, I will call the next line
        $("#filter_search").attr('href', "{{ url_for('filter_search', entities='{0}', data='{1}'.format(entities, data) )}}");

        //Then, if all goes as planned, it will change the href and redirect the user to filtered_search 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it the way you want, because the template runs in the server and your jQuery function runs in the client.

The sequence of operations is as follows:

- the client requests the page
- the server generates the response by rendering the template. Any `url_for()` or other Python code in the templates runs at this time
- the client receives the page and executes the Javascript in it
- Your jQuery function finally executes, but by then it is too late to change the output of `url_for()`.

What you have to do to make this work is build your URLs in Javascript.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19885146/904393), where I propose two possible solutions to a similar question.